# Can't update bundler

Tags: ubuntu, bundler

When running any `bundle` command, I see `Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running 'gem install bundler'.` Then I run command `gem install bundler`, it requires permissions, then I use `sudo` and

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But when using `bundle version`, I see `Bundler version 1.11.2`. How to fix that?